# Show a identity on a compact set

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $r>0$ and $S_r^2$ the sphere with ratio $r>0$ such that $S_r^{2}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: \|x\|=r\}.$ For example, $S^2=S_1^{2}.$ Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function and define $g(x)=f(rx).$ Show that $$\displaystyle\int_{S^{2}_r} fdA=r^2\displaystyle\int_{S^{2}} gdA.$$

Hello, for this problem is necessary use the definition of surface integral? If $\displaystyle\int fdA$ this define on $S_r^{2}$, then I need the parametrization?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Change of Variables formula. You have a map  $\phi: x \mapsto rx$ which is a diffeomorphism of the domains for $f,g$. And so if we restrict $\phi$ to the sphere $S_1^2$ then $\phi(S_1^2) = S_r^2$. Hence we have that,

\begin{align*} \int_{S_r^2} f \ dA &= \int_{S^2_1} (f \circ \phi) |\textbf{det}(J(\phi))| \ dA  \\ & = r^2\int_{S^2} g \ dA\end{align*}

$\textbf{Edit}$: Ted Shifrin is correct. I shouldn't be thinking of the map on $S^2$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but the map on the surfaces themselves induced by charts. In this case the reparametrization $\phi$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix .

Comment: Thanks @FaraadArmwood. My question is how solve the integral for conclude that is $r^3\displaystyle\int_{S^2} gdA$?

Comment: @Julio_fmat You can explicitly solve that integral in the numerical sense, since $g$ and $f$ are explicitly defined. Your question just asks to show the relation.

Comment: @Julio_fmat: Also, you have an extremely low answer acceptance ratio. If users spend time posting, you should at least comment or accept a solution if it helped you.

Comment: No, $r^2$, not $r^3$. This is a surface integral, not a volume integral, so you don't have the right Jacobian.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you. I made the appropriate edit and comment.

Comment: @Faraad Sorry, but I don't understand how solve this integral. For example, how calculate the Jacobian matrix?

Comment: You don't need to solve the integral. You are calculating the jacobian of $\phi(u,v) = r(u,v)$ which is,  $$ D\phi(u,v) = \begin{pmatrix} r & 0 \\ 0 & r \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Faraad Thanks, but then $\varphi$ isn't define of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Because then $D\varphi(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}{r}&{0}&{0}\\{0}&{r}&{0}\\{0}&{0}&{r}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I know. That's why I changed the domain and range of $\phi$. At first I took the mapping between the spheres, but as sub manifolds and so the matrix is $3 \times 3$. However, this is supposed to be a surface integral, i.e $\phi$ should just be a map on the surfaces. This is why I wrote $\phi(u,v) = r(u,v)$.